# Pyspark dataframe split alphabetically and write to S3

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to split a huge XML file into small XML files using pyspark. I need the data to be written into buckets alphabetically.

Suppose if the name starts with `a` then it would be written to an s3 bucket `s3://bucket_name/a`. If there is no name that starts with `b` it  should still create a folder with name b in the same bucket, that is `s3://bucket_name/b`

So far the code I have is

```
charater = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

for c in charater:
    df1 = df.filter(lower(trim(col('name')).substr(1, 1)) == c)
    df1.write\
     .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
     .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 800)\
     .option("rootTag","source")\
     .option("rowTag", "employees")\
     .mode("overwrite")\
     .save(f's3://split-files/{c}')
```

But this code takes a very long time to finish. Is there a better way to do this using data frames?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `df.persist()` before the `for` loop.

Comment: @Steven That worked. Thank you so much. If you can post it as an answer, will accept it.

Comment: @Steven Another question, the writer creates a lot of part files with size 1B. Is there a way to avoid that? If needed I can create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the time use `df.persist()` before the `for loop` as suggested by `@Steven`

For the small files issue you can use coalesce but this is expensive operation.

```
for c in charater:
    df1 = df.filter(lower(trim(col('name')).substr(1, 1)) == c)
    df1.coalesce(1).write\
     .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
     .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 800)\
     .option("rootTag","source")\
     .option("rowTag", "employees")\
     .mode("overwrite")\
     .save(f's3://split-files/{c}')
```

This will create only one file in each bucket. you can change the number of files you want by specifying to `coalesce` function

Comment: I tried to coalesce 1, it did create a single file, but that single file turned out to be a huge file again, defeating the purpose of the task. I added `df = df.repartition(40)` ad it created 40 part files. I am new to this and trying to figure out if there is any downside to adding this.

Comment: @Jilna `Coalesce and repartition` are concepts in `spark` where you are trying to partition the data frames.  `coalesce` is much better than `repartition` because it involves less shuffling of data please have a look at `https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce/`

Comment: Got it. Thank you. That helped. With this logic, it currently takes  240-253 secs to read and write an 8GB file to S3.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I see is to use write with partition by clause and process the whole data at a single go, the only draw back i is the folder name will be s3://bucket_name/char_name=a instead of s3://bucket_name/a which you are expecting , you could rename the bucket name if you really want to stick to the folder name

```
df = df.withColumn('char_name', df['name'].substr(1, 1))
df1.repartition("char_name").write\
     .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
     .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 800)\
     .option("rootTag","source")\
     .option("rowTag", "employees")\
     .mode("overwrite")\
     .save(f's3://split-files/')
```

There is no need to do a for loop.

if there is absolute need of folder to be present , You can do a left outer join to the alphabet list and create all records. I added a extra column but you can drop of rename as per ur need

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)
df_list = spark.createDataFrame(alphabet_list, StringType())
df = df.withColumn('char_name', df['name'].substr(1, 1))
df.createOrReplace("data")
df_list.createOrReplace("misssingalphabet")
df_final=spark.sql("select A.value as all_char_name,B.* from misssingalphabet A left outer join data B on A.value = B.char_name")
df_final.repartition("all_char_name").write\
     .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
     .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 800)\
     .option("rootTag","source")\
     .option("rowTag", "employees")\
     .mode("overwrite")\
     .save(f's3://split-files/')
```

Comment: I thought of this but the problem I saw with this approach is that it does not create empty folders when no record for a specific alphabet exists. Referring to this part of the question " If there is no name that starts with b it should still create a folder with name b in the same bucket, that is s3://bucket_name/b"

Comment: if there is absolute need of folder to be present , You can do a left outer join to the alphabet list and create all records. Because if folder present spark read that as row , if you have downstream reading this , u get a empty line while processing